# How to compare two different files and extract overlapping data?

Tags: linux, shell, grep, comm

I am a newcomer to the world of programming, so if I just asked an easy or obvious question, please forgive me. I really need A LOT of help.

I currently have two sets of data.

The first one looks like this (call it file1):

```
GeneName
TAF13
ZC3H6
RAC3
MED16
FAT3
SCRG1
GRM3
DHX16
LRRN4CL
STMN4
PCDHGA11
RPLP1
WASF1
KATNAL1
FTL1
D8ERTD738E
```

The second one looks like this (call it "file2"):

```
GeneName    Chr Start   End SumOfMerge  67_1    67_2    67_3    68_1    68_2    68_3    69_1    69_2    69_3    70_1    70_2    70_3    71_1    71_2    71_3    72_1    72_2    72_3    73_1    73_2    73_3    
LOC100288069    chr1    713126  714875  13  NA  nPk1    nPk1    NA  nPk1    nPk1    NA  NA  nPk1    NA  nPk2    nPk1    NA  nPk1    nPk1    NA  nPk1    nPk1    NA  nPk1    nPk1    
FAM87B  chr1    752176  752900  20  nPk2    nPk3    nPk2    nPk2    nPk3    nPk3    nPk2    nPk3    nPk3    nPk2    nPk4    NA  nPk3    nPk3    nPk3    nPk3    nPk3    nPk2    nPk2    nPk3    nPk3    
LINC00115   chr1    761026  763300  20  nPk7    nPk6    nPk3    nPk7    nPk5    nPk4    nPk7    nPk8    nPk5    NA  nPk5    nPk3    nPk8    nPk6    nPk4    nPk7    nPk7    nPk3    nPk8    nPk7    nPk4    
SAMD11  chr1    858401  862175  20  nPk16   NA  nPk10   nPk16   nPk13   nPk13|nPk14 nPk16   nPk16   nPk13   nPk14   nPk13   NA  nPk18   nPk13   nPk11|nPk12 nPk17   NA  nPk12   nPk17   nPk16   nPk11   
KLHL17|NOC2L    chr1    892751  897375  21  nPk23   nPk14   nPk15   nPk24|nPk25 NA  nPk18   nPk25   nPk20   nPk18   nPk24   nPk18   nPk10   nPk27|nPk28 nPk17   NA  nPk25   nPk18   nPk18   nPk24   nPk20   nPk16   
HES4    chr1    934201  937725  14  nPk30   nPk19   nPk19   NA  nPk24   nPk22   nPk33   nPk25   nPk22   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  nPk23   nPk32   nPk23   nPk22   NA  nPk25   nPk20   
ISG15   chr1    948076  948750  7   nPk32   NA  NA  nPk33   NA  NA  nPk36   NA  NA  nPk35   NA  NA  nPk37   NA  NA  nPk34   NA  NA  nPk36   NA  NA  
AGRN    chr1    954376  954875  21  nPk34   nPk22   nPk21   nPk36   nPk27   nPk24   nPk38   nPk28   nPk24   nPk37   nPk24   nPk16   nPk39   nPk24   nPk25   nPk36   nPk26   nPk24   nPk38   nPk28   nPk22   
AGRN    chr1    954951  955275  11  NA  NA  nPk22   NA  nPk28   nPk25   NA  nPk29   nPk25   NA  nPk25   nPk17   NA  NA  nPk26   NA  nPk27   nPk25   NA  NA  nPk23   
C1orf159    chr1    1051051 1052500 21  nPk53   nPk38   nPk37   nPk56   nPk42   nPk39   nPk60   nPk42   nPk41   nPk54   nPk38   nPk25   nPk55   nPk40   nPk40   nPk57   nPk45   nPk38   nPk55   nPk50   nPk38   
LINC01342   chr1    1070301 1073175 2   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  nPk40   nPk28   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  
TTLL10  chr1    1108776 1109450 1   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  nPk65   Na  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  
TNFRSF4 chr1    1150276 1150750 2   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  nPk72   NA  NA  nPk72   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  
SDF4    chr1    1165926 1167475 4   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  nPk48   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  nPk50   NA  NA  nPk45   NA  NA  nPk46
```

Please forgive me if the second data came out really messy, it is actually a data with 26 columns each separated by tab space.

My objective is to compare file1 and file2 by the first column "GeneName" and extract lines from file2 to a new file, file3.

file3 should look like file2 except would only contain lines that have the same GeneName as file1.

Currently, I have tried with `comm` and `join` and `grep -f`, none gave the solution I want. I think `grep` might be enough to do the work, but I don't know the correct options. If there are any other possible solutions to this problem, please share with me. Thank you for the time!

Comment: This would be fairly easy with Python. Do you have any experience with it, or would that be acceptable?

Comment: @Alden I am not familiar with it, but I can try my best to comprehend the code. Thanks, anyway! :)

Answer (score 2):

Grep + bash:

```
grep -f <(tail -n +2 file1 | sed 's/^/^/g') file2 > file3
```

This will remove the `GeneName` column (skipping first line using `tail -n +2` - start printing from the second line) and add `^` (regexp for beginning of line) to the beginning of each line - such list is a good one for `grep -f` to match the lines and write them to file3.

This assumes you don't want the header (GeneName) line in the output.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I tried the code but the resulting file is completely blank. I checked that there is overlapping data, so there should be at least a few lines. Also, can you explain a little more about the purpose of replacing GeneName with ^? Thank you!

Comment: @DLee `grep -v` is for printing all lines that do NOT match, I've replaced it with tail

Comment: @DLee Do you have a real life examples that would match? I tested it with my example and it works, so there might be some problems with the input.

Comment: @krzyk The data I gave are real life examples, except that I didn't post the whole thing, the files are too big. I just discovered that excel is actually sufficient to do what I want, with '=VLOOKUP()'. I will still try again with your code. Thank you for all the help!!

Comment: @DLee OK, but your example in the question will result in empty file3 as there are not matches

Answer (score 1):

How do you feel about a little python code?

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys, re

lookup = {}
for line in open( sys.argv[1] ).readlines():
  lookup[line.rstrip()] = True

for line in open( sys.argv[2] ).readlines():
  s = re.split('[\t ]+', line)
  if len(s) > 0 and s[0] in lookup:
    print( line.rstrip() )
```

If the file is saved as py.py, then:

```
chmod 755 py.py
./py.py file1 file2 > file3
```

At this point you might want to tweak the file a bit to not be case sensitive?  Add .lower() to the lookup key and the s[0].